# Where can I find the Night Shade TM?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

I want to teach a Pokemon Night Shade, but do not have the TM for it, and the Move Tutor will not teach my Pokemon. I know this doesn't mean the Pokemon cannot learn the move, because a Hypno learned Dream Eater with its TM, and Move Tutor didn't teach it. Where can I find Night Shade's TM?

Comment: There is no TM that teaches Night Shade and no tutors that can teach Night Shade. What Pokemon do you want to teach Night Shade exactly? Hypno cannot learn Night Shade though, and Dream Eater is a Psychic attack (not that it matters though).

Comment: Actually, it does matter. It is a Hypno I would like to teach Night Shade. I know Dream Eater is a Psychic attack because TMs tell you types, but I know that some Psycic types can learn certain Ghost moves (Hypno knows Nightmare to go along with Hypnosis), so... I can't teach the Pokemon Night Shade.

Comment: What I meant by "not that it matters" is that Pokemon can learn all sorts of moves, even if the move is not of the same type as they are, and in some cases, they can't even learn moves of their own type (e.g. Caterpie can learn only 2 bug moves out of the plethora of bug moves). It doesn't matter that they can learn one type of move, what really matters is whether they can or cannot learn one particular move. In your case, no, Hypno cannot learn Night Shade at all. Nightmare and Shadow Ball are the only ghost moves it can learn (it could learn Curse back in Gold/Silver/Crystal though).

Answer (score 2):

Not all moves have corresponding [TM](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/TM)s to teach them; in fact the majority do not. [Night Shade](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Night_Shade_%28move%29) is one of them; is does not and has never had a TM. It can only be learned by certain Pokémon through level-up or breeding.